# ¿Como puedo editar una linea de texto en especifico en BATCH?

Tags: windows, batch

POR FAVOR NO ME CIERREN LA PREGUNTA :( No he encontrado ninguna solución para mi en ningún lado.

**Estoy intentando hacer un batch para que la gente que lo necesite lo pueda descargar, así que no puedo prescindir de extensiones de comandos. Es un procedimiento largo lo que quiero hacer si se hace manualmente, por eso hago este BATCH, pero me he atrancado en este tema.**

El problema es que no se como cambiar una **linea específica** desde batch.

Otro problema es que la linea de texto que quiero modificar puede ser un numero aleatorio asi que no podria buscar un texto en específico.

La línea del archivo que quiero modificar es la *10317*, pero ya he dicho que el contenido de esta linea puede variar.
Si hace falta que cree un archivo VBS temporal no pasa nada, pero realmente prefiero que sea en batch.

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué llevas escrito? ¿En qué parte de tu código no encuentras la solución?

Comment: Tengo mucho escrito, solo quiero saber que necesito. Son demasiadas lineas como para que las ponga aquí, lo siento :(
Literalmente sólo me queda eso para terminar el programa, porque lo deje para el final.

Imagina que tengo que reemplazar la linea 10317 en el archivo "ejemplo.txt"